# Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync not returning Recurrence series enddate in OWA if the meeting created in Native with End After option

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-app

We are creating a recurring meeting in **Outlook Native** with option **End After option** like below.

[Recurrence created with End After option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPShq.png)

We have developed an **Office Add-In** in which uses **Office.js** built-in **Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync** function to fetch recurrence details. This function is working correctly when we fetch recurrence details in our Add-In in Outlook Native and gives the **recurrence series endDay, endMonth and endYear**.

[Fetching recurrence details in Native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIa4j.png)

But the same function is not returning endDay, endMonth and endYear instead it is returning 0 in all three properties when we open the same meeting in **OWA**, load our Add-In and fetch the recurrence details.

[Fecthing recurrence details in OWA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AOap.png)

**Recurrence series endDay, endMonth and endYear** must be returned from above function in case of OWA also.